# Force controller rendering in head of page to render after other renderings

Tags: presentation, mvc

I know that MVC and by definition Sitecore MVC renders components from top to bottom order, but is there any way to force (hack) a controller rendering (which is used in the head of the page) to be rendered *after* another specific rendering lower down in the page?

I know this kind of makes an implied dependency which is crappy and generally goes against the philosophy of MVC, but I don't see another way around this particular problem. All the markup needs to be in place in the page at the point of page load, so a JavaScript-based solution won't work here, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep. There are various ways to go about it. Here is one.

```
@using Sitecore.Mvc
@{
    Layout = null;

    HtmlString main = Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("MAIN");
    HtmlString head = Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("HEAD");
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>@Html.Sitecore().Field("title", new { DisableWebEdit = true })</title>
    @head
</head>

<body>
    <h1>@Html.Sitecore().Field("title")</h1>
    <h2>Cross component comms layout</h2>
    <div>
        @main
    </div>
</body>

</html
```

Here, `main` is rendered before `head` (which is what you ask for), yet still output in the correct order in the document.

Source: [GETTING MVC COMPONENTS TO COMMUNICATE](https://jermdavis.wordpress.com/2016/04/04/getting-mvc-components-to-communicate/)

Additional reference:

- [Controlling Rendering Order in Sitecore MVC](https://kamsar.net/index.php/2017/01/Controlling-Rendering-Order-in-Sitecore-MVC/)

Comment: Dammit! I see a question I could answer and you've already linked to my blog post on the topic! I am too slow for this malarky... ;-)